# React-native forceUpdate() is undefined

Tags: react-native, uicomponents

I have a problem with forceUpdate() call.
Here is my native component export:

```
class iface extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <MRECView {...this.props} />;
    }
}
var MRECView = requireNativeComponent('MrecView', iface);
export default MRECView;
```

After that, I added my component to screen with a reference:

```
<MRECView ref={ component => {this.mrecView = component;}} style={{ height: 250, width: 300, marginTop: 8, flex: 0}} />
```

And the last thing is to call forceUpdate in on button clicked callback:

```
this.mrecView.forceUpdate();
```

But instead of update I received an error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.mrecView.forceUpdate()')
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Some technical details:

React v15.4.2

React-Native v0.42.0

Comment: Can you provide how do you set onButtonClick callback? Might be that `this` is referencing to the wrong this.

Comment: @PatrikPrevuznak here is an example: https://gist.github.com/Tamplier/5428ce8fc95259c50d8ea04651528205